# Lock and unlock in solidity

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I  want to create a simple smart contract, where initial supply is 1000 and send 1000 to a specific wallet. Now
I want the supply of wallet(1000) to be locked for a year and every month a 5% of that supply should be added to initial supply.

So far I've developed this:

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Timer{

    uint256 public  intialSuply= 1000;
    address public wallet= 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    address public  owner;
    mapping (address=>uint) public  balances;
    
    constructor(){
        owner=msg.sender;
         balances[wallet]=1000;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        
        require(owner==msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    
    function locker()public {

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you need:

I modified your code to include logic to unlock 5 percent of the tokens. I added comments as suggestions and clarification.

There are about 2,628,288 seconds on average in a month. So I used this number to calculate the difference between the current `block.timestamp` and the time we last updated/calculated the 5 percent that you need.

After a month, you, as the owner, will need to call the `unlock5Percent()` function manually, so it checks what it needs to check and do the calculation and update the tokens.

You can change this approach according to your needs.

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Timer{

    uint256 public constant intialSuply = 1000;
    uint256 private totalSupply;
    address public wallet = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    uint256 public constant SECONDS_IN_A_MONTH = 2_628_288;
    uint256 public constant SECONDS_IN_A_YEAR = 31_536_000;
    uint256 public lastUpdated;
    uint256 public immutable initialTimestamp;
    
    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
        // Minted and locked 1000 tokens
        balances[wallet] = 1000;
        // balances[address(this)] = intialSuply; // Maybe you also want to initialize this contract with most tokens?
        lastUpdated = block.timestamp;
        initialTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(owner==msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function unlock5Percent() public onlyOwner {

        // If a year has passed, then release all the locked funds in `balances[wallet]`
        // and add them to the `balances[address(this)]`.
        if(block.timestamp - initialTimestamp >= SECONDS_IN_A_YEAR) {
            uint256 lockedFunds = balances[wallet];
            balances[wallet] = 0;
            balances[address(this)] = lockedFunds;
            totalSupply += lockedFunds;
        }

        // If a month has passed after we last updated the locked tokens, by calculating that the difference, the time passed
        // between the last update, has been a month or more
        // then we can extract 5 percent more
        else if(block.timestamp - lastUpdated >= SECONDS_IN_A_MONTH) {

            // Devide any number by 20 and you get the 5 percent of that number.
            // In Solidity we cannot use an expression like `100 * 0.05` to get the 5 percent value of a number
            // Because Solidity does not support operations on floating point numbers.
            // So we either have to do the operation in another way or use a math library for Solidity that has this capability. 
            uint256 fivePercentage = balances[wallet] / 20;

            // Remove 5 percent of the tokens from the wallet
            balances[wallet] -= fivePercentage;

            // Andd add it to this contract's token supply
            balances[address(this)] += fivePercentage;

            // Are we considering `totalSupply` to be the amount of tokens in circulation or are we
            // counting the 'locked' tokens also as part of the `totalSupply`?
            totalSupply += fivePercentage;

            // Don't forget to update the lastUpdated variable so we only allow to extract 5 percent more after another month
            lastUpdated = block.timestamp;
        }
        
    }

    // In this example, the sender is able to spend his tokens.
    function transfer(address to, uint256 _amount) public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Not enough balance");
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        balances[to] += _amount;
    }

    // In this example, only the owner is able to spend the tokens of this contract
    function transferTo(address to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(balances[address(this)] >= _amount, "Not enough balance");
        balances[address(this)] -= _amount;
        balances[to] += _amount;
    }
    
}
```

I included some logic to lock for a year too. Also, a couple of examples on how to transfer tokens to other addresses, etc.

Comment: Hi @jeremy But why the total supply of the tokens not being managed? it was neither mentioned in constructor nor it was increased during the execution of 

function unlock5Percent

am i missing anything imp here?

Comment: @jeremy , you did not lock the supply in wallets for 365 days.

Comment: another point when you do this 

balances[address(this)] = fivePercentage;

that mean the token balance is assigned for contract address but like we know that Contracts can't sign by their own how  this balance will move transfered in future?

Comment: The name of the variable `intialSuply` seems like information and that should not be updated since it's the initial supply that everybody should be able to see.
I added a new `totalSupply` variable for this one to be updated when you mint tokens.

Comment: I added a simple logic for you as a guide. You can add any other logic you think you need for your token. Yes, you would also need to write logic to handle the tokens under the contract address `balances[address(this)]`. I did not write the logic for it, I leave it to you to write logic as you need.

Comment: The code that I wrote is for you to use as a guide or starting point. Feel free to play around with it and change anything that you need.

Comment: I already updated it. Thanks.