# How to mint or release a new token every second?

Tags: tokens

Hello is it possible to make a token with a mint function that can automatically be minting or release a new token every second?
Using this function

```
 function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
```

Also this token can be bought but locked for 2 years and investors wont be able to sell it until after 2 years..

please i need further details and help on this or any Open source i can use if possible..

Comment: Take a look at [Sablier](https://sablier.finance/) - it should be the perfect tool for your needs. Disclaimer - I'm a founder.

Answer (score 3):

minting every second is not feasible as the blockchain produces blocks every 10-12 seconds and as the blockchain executes the transaction when the block is pushed to the blockchain. You could only have timestamp difference between two blocks.

If you want to mint every block you could use a task from [gelato](https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/automate) that allows you to run any custom logic every block.

One pattern I use to lock tokens is keep track of the timestamp and override the `beforeTokenTransfer` reverting if the timestamp + lock has not yet arrived.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to make a function that mints every second.
The answer to your question can be divided into 2 parts.

1. Minting every second

After creating the mint function, you will have to call it in a loop in node.js or a similar backend with a timeout of 1 second or a similar time loop logic.

2. For locking the transfer after minting there is a really good answer that exists using block.timestamp

[Lock and unlock in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135075/lock-and-unlock-in-solidity)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using [the Sablier protocol](https://sablier.com) (disclosure: I'm part of of the team at Sablier). The protocol allows you to stream ERC-20 tokens, where every second a fraction of the total amount is streamed over to the recipient.

Here is a quick example of how this works in practice:

> Imagine Alice wants to stream 3,000 DAI to Bob during the whole month of January.
>
> 1. Alice deposits the 3,000 DAI in Sablier before Jan 1, setting the end time to Feb 1.
> 2. Bob's allocation of the DAI deposit increases every second beginning Jan 1.
> 3. On Jan 10, Bob will have earned approximately 1,000 DAI. He can send a transaction to Sablier to withdraw the tokens.
> 4. If at any point during January Alice wishes to get back her tokens, she can cancel the stream and recover what has not been streamed yet.

The advantage of using Sablier is that it's hassle-free, meaning you wouldn't have to code anything given the protocol is battle-tested and has been running on the Ethereum and other chains since 2019.

It is worth noting that you have the ability to enforce a cliff before the streaming period begins (for example, a six-month cliff).

More info is available in the [docs](https://docs.sablier.com/). Feel free to reach out on [Discord](https://discord.gg/bSwRCwWRsT) if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can mint a token on every block but not on every second because at least on EVM one block costs more than that to me mined.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be algorithmic minting and some dispatcher method. For example,

- the contract stores the time when the minting for the user was started or was for the last time.
- the contract has `withdraw` method, or another mechanic to mint the tokens of the amount **equal to the past seconds**.

For example, a user can start his minting period with the first `withdraw` transaction, every further transaction will mint the tokens for the user.

```typescript
contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    struct UserData {
        uint256 lastMintAt;
        // other user relative info, end time? tokens per second? etc
    }
    mapping(address => UserData) users;
   
    function widthdraw () public {
      // validate if the user can withdraw
      
      uint lastMintAt = users[msg.sender].lastMintAt;
      if (lastMintAt == 0) {
        users[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        return;
      }

      uint secondsPassed = block.timestamp - lastMintAt;

      require(secondsPassed > 0, "No time past");

      uint TOKENS_PER_SECOND = 1 ether;
      uint amount = secondsPassed * TOKENS_PER_SECOND;

      _mint(msg.sender, amount);
      users[msg.sender].lastMintAt = block.timestamp;
    }
}
```